# Terrain intersection performance

Tags: javascript, three.js

I create `var geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(512,512,255,255);` then parse jpg heightmap and change verticles' positions to receive deformed plane. Than I cast ray from the sky to the ground in the `animate()` function to get intersection point:

```
var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster( new THREE.Vector3(player.x, 100, player.z), new THREE.Vector3(0, -1, 0) );
var intersects = raycaster.intersectObject( ground, true );
if(intersects.length == 1) {
    mesh.position.set(intersects[0].point.x, intersects[0].point.y, intersects[0].point.z);
}
```

But FPS become very low (<20). I also tried to get y-position through the height map, but texture is only 256 x 256, so if I want to make mesh follow the terrain the y-coordinate is jerking.

Comment: Did I get it correctly that you create two new vectors on each render?

Comment: actually you just need to get the grounds height at a certain position dont you?

Comment: @prisoner849 I have to create first vector each frame because player.x and player.y can change.

Comment: @JonasW. yes, you're right.

Comment: i dont think that you need to recalc the height on every frame. just do thaton every 10th render or so

Comment: @Kittyhawk Instantiate a vector once and re-use it. Could you create [mcve]?

Comment: @JonasW. I tried, but FPS is still <45. hordes.io somehow works on 60 FPS with the same height map.

Comment: Would be curious how you're using "terrain intersection" here? For something like clamping the player to the ground, [three-pathfinding](https://github.com/donmccurdy/three-pathfinding) might be easier.

Comment: @prisoner849 I created a pen, but I can't realise how to use non-local image: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mxwrLN

Comment: Just a note: `Raycaster` checks against ALL faces in a mesh. For your case, it's `255`x`255`x`2` = `130050` faces. If you're doing this in your `animate` function, then you're doing it EVERY FRAME. That's very likely to slow down your framerate.

Comment: @TheJim01 I know. Maybe tiling can help?

Comment: Yes. Break your mesh into multiple meshes. Just keep in mind that you'll need to account for the offsets in your displacement mapping. If your raycaster is being fired perpendicular to the original plane, then you can essentially "know" which mesh to ray cast. (If you're only adjusting the Y values, then you know the XZ bounds of each mesh, and can check the ray's XZ to determine which mesh to cast against).

Comment: @TheJim01 Ok, I'll try it. Also I think I can a little bit improve described in the post solution, that uses height map to get height of the terrain on specific point. If I will identify triangle of the ground that is right below the mesh and than using coordinates (x;z) of the mesh and positions of 3 vertices I can get y of the point on this face without jerking while moving mesh.

Answer (score 1):

Try to calculate as few as possible directly in the loop. This also means that you should allocate the raycaster outside of the loop. And using the range might also help to speed up raycasting:

```
 const direction = new THREE.Vector3(0, -1, 0);
 const position = new THREE.Vector3(player.x, 100, player.z);

 const raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster(position, direction, 0, 200);

 let y = 0;
 let count = 0;
```

Then inside the loop just sometimes recalculate the height:

```
 if(count = (count + 1) % 10){
   position.set(player.x, 100, player.z);
   y = raycaster.intersectObject( ground, true );
 }

 mesh.position.set(player.x, y, player.z);
```

Comment: FPS is still ~25.

Comment: @Kittyhawk what is ground?

Comment: Plane deformed with height map.

Comment: @kittyhawk maybe its mesh.position.set ? or some other code? have you checked that?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. This is my animate function with you code: https://pastebin.com/R3mP4UNF